# how to hql "left join fetch" and with

Tags: left-join, fetch

how do when I'm using fetch? "with" does not work.

```
ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetSession();

string sql = "FROM Filial fi " +
             "left join fetch fi.LstUsuario usr " +
             "with usr.NumSequencial = :idUsr " +
             "order by fi.Nome";

IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(sql);

query.SetParameter("idUsr", usuario.NumSequencial, NHibernateUtil.Int64);

lstFilial = (List<Filial>)query.List<Filial>();
```

Error message: unexpected token: with [FROM Entidade.Filial fi left join fetch fi.LstUsuario usr with usr.NumSequencial = :idUsr order by fi.Nome]

**Code in SQL**

```
select *
from TFILIAL fi
  left join TPERMIS_USR_FILIAL usrFi
    on fi.anum_sequ_filial = usrfi.anum_sequ_filial
    and usrfi.anum_sequ_usuario = 2;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nobody has any idea? I'm really in need.

Comment: Man, do not have a question I ask here someone responds. Already edit my question to remove the end thanks, for this is people willing.

Comment: aren't you looking for the `where` keyword ?